# How to scale rectangles and positions based on view size on a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a project which I am working upon where after the user has inputted detail, a design gets created for them. The original version simply created the design on a basis that one inch is 72 pixels. I work off the same basis. However, I want to scale my design no matter how large or small the form is.

I have managed to create the design exactly like the original and I've also managed to scale the large rectangle(red) correctly but I don't know how to scale the smaller rectangles(black) down so they fit with the correct amount of space between each other.

It should look something like this:
[image: Design]

But when I attempt it, I get this:
[image: My design]

As you can see the smaller rectangle in mine are not in the correct x or y position and also are not split up like the design.

This is my code:

```
  private void ValidateFormBeforeDiagram(object sedner, OptionOneCheckedEventArgs e) {
    try {
        //Create variables
        int pagesUp = e.IsOptionOneChecked ? view.OptionOneAround : view.OptionTwoAround;
        int pagesAcross = e.IsOptionOneChecked ? view.OptionOneAcross : view.OptionTwoAcross;
        float pageWidth = e.IsOptionOneChecked ? view.PageSizeLength : view.PageSizeWidth;
        float pageLength = e.IsOptionOneChecked ? view.PageSizeWidth : view.PageSizeLength;


        ParametersToCreatePrintingDiagram parameters = new ParametersToCreatePrintingDiagram(view.SheetSizeAcross, view.SheetSizeAround,
            pagesUp, pagesAcross, pageWidth, pageLength);

        //Check if form is open, if so close it

        if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<PrintingDesignForm>().Any()) {
            Application.OpenForms.OfType<PrintingDesignForm>().First().Close();
        }

        //Create a new instance of the form
        PrintingDesignForm form = new PrintingDesignForm();
        float ratio = 0;

        //If rectangle is larger than the client viewable size then scale the rectangle so it will fit.
        if (parameters.RectangleHeight > form.ClientRectangle.Height || parameters.RectangleWidth > form.ClientRectangle.Height) {
            var ratioX = form.ClientRectangle.Height / parameters.RectangleHeight;
            var ratioY = form.ClientRectangle.Width / parameters.RectangleWidth;

            ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

            parameters.RectangleHeight = parameters.RectangleHeight * ratio - parameters.RectangleXPosition;
            parameters.RectangleWidth = parameters.RectangleWidth * ratio - parameters.RectangleYPosition;
        }

        //Draw the main rectangle
        form.Paint += (se, pe) => {
            var r = new Rectangle(parameters.RectangleXPosition, parameters.RectangleYPosition,
                (int)Math.Round(parameters.RectangleWidth), (int)Math.Round(parameters.RectangleHeight));

            var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 204));

            pe.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, r);
            using (var pen = new Pen(brush.Color, 2))
                pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, r);
        };

        float leftXInches;
        float topYInches;
        float xInch = 0;
        float yInch = 0;
        List<Rectangle> liRect = new List<Rectangle>();


        //Calculate the smaller rectangle sizes and positions
        for (int i = 1; i < parameters.PagesUp; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < parameters.PagesAcross; j++) {
                if (e.IsOptionOneChecked) {
                    leftXInches = parameters.RectangleXPosition
                    + ((view.SheetSizeAcross - (view.PageSizeLength * view.OptionOneAcross) - (view.OptionOneAcross - 1) * view.Bleeds) / 2)
                    + ((j - 1) * parameters.PageWidth)
                    + ((j - 1) * view.Bleeds);

                    topYInches = parameters.RectangleYPosition
                    + ((view.SheetSizeAround - (view.PageSizeLength * view.OptionOneAround) - (view.OptionOneAround - 1) * view.Bleeds) / 2)
                    + ((i - 1) * parameters.PageHeight)
                    + ((i - 1) * view.Bleeds);

                }
                else {

                    leftXInches = parameters.RectangleXPosition
                 + ((view.SheetSizeAcross - (view.PageSizeWidth * view.OptionTwoAcross) - (view.OptionTwoAcross - 1) * view.Bleeds) / 2)
                 + ((j - 1) * parameters.PageWidth)
                 + ((j - 1) * view.Bleeds);

                    topYInches = parameters.RectangleYPosition
                 + ((view.SheetSizeAround - (view.PageSizeLength * view.OptionTwoAround) - (view.OptionTwoAround - 1) * view.Bleeds) / 2)
                 + ((i - 1) * parameters.PageHeight)
                 + ((i - 1) * view.Bleeds);
                }

                var width = (Math.Round(parameters.PageWidth) * 72);
                var height = (Math.Round(parameters.PageHeight) * 72);

                yInch = (topYInches * 72);

                xInch = (leftXInches * 72);

                liRect.Add(new Rectangle((int)Math.Round(xInch * ratio), (int)Math.Round(yInch * ratio), (int)Math.Round(width * ratio),
                    (int)Math.Round(height * ratio)));
            }
        }

        //Paint the smaller rectangles onto the form
        for (int i = 0; i < liRect.Count; i++) {
            //Have to use x as i will only be the last increment of i due to form.Paint being an event.
            int x = i;

            form.Paint += (se, pe) => {
                var r = liRect[x];

                var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0));

                pe.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, r);
                using (var pen = new Pen(brush.Color, 2))
                    pe.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, r);
            };
        }

        form.Show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        LogErrorToView(this, new ErrorEventArgs(ex.Message));
    }
}
```

So how can I resize the smaller rectangle to fit in the larger rectangle with the correct amount of space between them?

I've been stuck on this issue for a while and would appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the option to upgrade the .NET framework for your project? In the MSBuild presentation, they went over this problem and that some scenarios were fixed in the newest .NET framework. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt799789(v=vs.110).aspx). Note: It may not fix your issue, though, but could be worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I took a look but I don't think it will help me